# Cache not updating

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am a newbie to angularfire so pardon me if I am asking something stupid and i will be thankful if someone will guide me through it. I have this code

```
this.checkIfExisitingUser(ussr.uid).take(1).subscribe((user: any) => { console.log(user) } 


checkIfExisitingUser(userId) {
return this.afs.collection('users', ref =>   ref.where('user_id', '==', userId)).snapshotChanges().map(actions => {

return  actions; 

}); 
}) 
}
```

The problem is the data in action is always an old one. The SnapshotMetadata always has fromCache:true and the actual data in database is different. Is there a way to bypass the cache or must update it? I think its not getting updated.

PS if anyone can guide me why isnt it updating. Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: map always works when its in subscribe ,are you subscribing it somewhere post snapshotChanges()?

Comment: Yes I am, please check the updated questions. Plus I know action doesnt directly has the user and user can be extracted from it but it is something like this.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata
can you try changing the onSnapshot() function to include snapshot listening options

Comment: Its as follows

metadata:SnapshotMetadata
fromCache:true
hasPendingWrites:false